# How to access Excel PROTECTED spreadsheet in SharePoint Web Access Web Part in SharePoint2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server, excel-services

I have excel file which is protected by password. I need to access Sheet 1 on SharePoint Web Part Page on Dashboard. While I add protected I can not able to Excel Sheet is corrupted as per below image.!

[image]

While I add simple Excel Spreadsheet, it works properly. Is there any alternate solution to display excel spreadsheet on Web Page using Excel Services.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not supported in Excel services.

I think Office Web Apps supports it in a specific version.

Comment: I'm trying to open SSAS cube from MS Office 2013